# Need for clarification with pointer behaviour

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Suppose I have an array `int a[] = {2, 3, 4};`
Why can a pointer to the first element `&a[0]` point to array elements, or values in general, but the pointer &a cannot?

```cpp
cout << (&a[0])[1]; // 3
cout << (&a)[0]; // some weird adress (presumably of the array itself
cout << (&a)[1]; 
// a higher adress probably the adress after the end of the array so &a + 0xC (length of array) + 0x1
```

Does the pointer itself (&a), type (something with int (*)...) act like some sort of array?

Comment: do the same experiment with `struct s { int x, y , z;} b;` and compare findings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays and pointers are two different types in C++ that have enough similarities between them to create confusion if they are not understood properly. The fact that pointers are one of the most difficult concepts for beginners to grasp doesn't help either.

So I fell a quick crash course is needed.

## Crash course

### Arrays, easy

```
int a[3] = {2, 3, 4};
```

This creates an array named `a` that contains 3 elements.

Arrays have defined the *array subscript* operator:

```
a[i]
```

evaluates to the `i`'th element of the array.

### Pointers, easy

```
int val = 24;
int* p = &val;
```

`p` is a pointer pointing to the address of the object `val`.

Pointers have the *indirection (dereference)* operator defined:

```
*p
```

evaluates to the value of the object pointed by `p`.

### Pointers, acting like arrays

Pointers give you the address of an object in memory. It can be a "standalone object" like in the example above, or it can be an object that is part of an array. Neither the pointer type nor the pointer value can tell you which one it is. Just the programmer. That's why

Pointers also have the *array subscript* operator defined:

`p[i]`

evaluates to the `i`th element to the "right" of the object pointed by `p`. This assumes that the object pointer by `p` is part of an array (except in `p[0]` where it doesn't need to be part of an array).

Note that `p[0]` is equivalent to (the exact same as) `*p`.

### Arrays, acting like pointers

In most contexts array names decay to a pointer to the first element in the array. That is why many beginners think that arrays and pointers are the same thing. In fact they are not. They are different types.

## Your examples

Going back to your examples.

> Why can a pointer to the first element `&a[0]` point to array elements, or values in general,

Now I hope you can see that if `p` points to the first element of the array `arr` then `p[i]` is equivalent to `arr[i]`. Since `&a[0]` is a pointer to the first element of the array then `(&a[0])[i]` is equivalent to `a[i]`.

> ... but the pointer `&a` cannot?

As I stated above, arrays are not pointer.

So a pointer to the array is not the same thing as a pointer to the first element of the array. Taking the address of the array is one of the few instances where the array name doesn't decay to a pointer to its first element.

So `&a` is a pointer to the array, *not* a pointer to the first element of the array. Both the array and the first element of the array start at the same address so the values of the two (`&a` and `&a[0]`) are the same, but their types are different and that matters when you apply the dereference or array subscript operator to them:

| Expression | Expression type | Dereference / array subscript expresison | Dereference / array subscript type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `a` | `int[3]` | `*a` / `a[i]` | `int` |
| `&a` | `int (*) [3]` (pointer to array) | `*&a` / `&a[i]` | `int[3]` |
| `&a[0]` | `int *` | `*&a[0]` / `(&a[0])[i]` | `int` |

Comment: Why is the subscripted `&a` returning a pointer, and not `int[3]` then?

Comment: `&` is the *address of* operator. `&x` will always be a pointer to the type of `x`.

Comment: Nevermind, it actually is dereferencing to the `int[3]` but this is decaying to `int *` (first element) again. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Raumschifffan can you please elaborate. To what expression are you refereeing? I want to make sure you got it right. Pointers and arrays and pointers to arrays get confusing very fast :)

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to `cout << (&a)[0];` returning an adress, I realized that this is the same as doing `cout << a;`, it even is the same data type.  C++ just can't print out arrays.

Comment: @Raumschifffan correct. When you pass an array to a function (as a parameter) the array decays. That's why `cout << a` doesn't receive the array, `a` decays to a pointer before being passed to `cout`. You could write a print templated function that takes an array by reference and that function could print the array by that is another discussion.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your very detailed explanation and comments. I think I am slowly getting the hang of it. Stay safe and have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

`&a` is a pointer to the array. When you indirect through that pointer, you get the pointed array.

`&a[0]` is - like you said - a pointer to an element of the array. When you indirect through that pointer, you get the pointed element.